# PostgreSQL - query optimalization or multiple loops needed

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table LCT_PRD_PROPERTIES that keeps properties assigned to each product. Each product can have more than one property assigned.

Structure of LCT_PRD_PROPERTIES table and examplary data:

```
PRS_ID;PRS_PRD_ID;PRS_PPS_ID
99;39;41;
106;41;41;
100;39;42;
103;40;42;
```

where PRS_PRD_ID is foreign key of product ID
and PRS_PPS_ID foreign key of property ID

Case: I want to receive PRD_ID only of these products that have both 41 and 42 PPS_ID's assigned.

Is there any better way than select in the first loop all PRD_ID's that have PPS_ID=41 assigned, and in the second loop, take result from the first loop and search these products that have also PPS_ID=42 assigned?

Regards
Michal

Comment: Where do `PRD_ID` and `PPS_ID` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

```
SELECT
    PRS_PRD_ID,
    count(PRS_PPS_ID) AS prop_count
FROM LCT_PRD_PROPERTIES
WHERE PRD_PPS_ID IN (?, ?, ...) /* <-- the properties you are searching for here */
GROUP BY PRS_PRD_ID
HAVING prop_count = ? /* value here equals number of properties being searched for */
```

What you are doing is querying all entries that have matching property ID's then performing an aggregate count on them by product ID.  Only those that have a count matching the same some of properties you are looking for, fulfill the search requirement.

Comment: No. I need to have a general query used in a procedure, that finds only these products that have all defined properties assigned.

Comment: This does that. Only product ID's that have all the properties you are searching for related in that table will be returned. It doesn't matter if you are searching for 1 property or 10 properties, this would work. You would just have a differing number of values in your `IN` clause and a different value you are comparing the count against in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: One minute, I will check that :)

Comment: @Michal You can also use aggregation for cases where you want to do approximate matches as well. So for example, instead of working with the count directly, you might say divided counted number of properties by number of properties being used for matching to get a 0 to 1 value in a column that you could sort by in descending order for "best match" (this would eliminate need for `HAVING` clause.